# How can I run Gunicorn/WSGI Flask application with SocketIO and Docopt arguments?

Tags: flask, socket.io, wsgi, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I am following this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04).

I am stuck at how to make my `wsgi.py`. The guide says the basic `wsgi.py` setup is like this.

```
from myproject import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My main entry for my Flask application is `server-pedge.py`. I run it with `python3 -B server_pedge.py --https -o` arguments from Docopt to starts it in HTTPS. Here are some parts from my `server_pedge.py`.

```
import database
import global_var
import rethinkdb as r
import subprocess

app       = Flask(__name__)
socket_io = SocketIO(app)

...

socket_io.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", ssl_context=https_context)
```

My current `wsgi.py` is like this.

```
from server_pedge import socket_io

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socket_io.run()
```

When running with Gunicorn there are these errors.

```
bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app
[2017-05-14 10:55:17 +0000] [4337] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-05-14 10:55:17 +0000] [4337] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (4337)
[2017-05-14 10:55:17 +0000] [4337] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-05-14 10:55:17 +0000] [4340] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4340
Failed to find application: 'wsgi'
[2017-05-14 10:55:18 +0000] [4340] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4340)
[2017-05-14 10:55:18 +0000] [4337] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-05-14 10:55:18 +0000] [4337] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

It is not even HTTPS. What is the fix here?

Comment: What directory are you running gunicorn from? You should be in the same directory as the ``wsgi.py`` file for it to be found. Also don't use ``bin/gunicorn``, use ``gunicorn`` and make sure it is in your PATH. Using a relative path to ``gunicorn`` may cause it not to look in the current directory.

Comment: `bin/gunicorn` is from the virtual environment of my Python projects. The `gunicorn` is able to find the `wsgi.py` so I think that is not a problem.

Comment: If you have activated the virtual environment properly as one should, you shouldn't need to say ``bin/gunicorn``. Specify just ``gunicorn``. If you can't, you haven't activated the virtual environment.

Comment: `which gunicorn` refer to system - wide installed `gunicorn` that I have uninstalled.